# Importance of Rama Nama

Tags: rama, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, name

We all know that the Lord has 1000s of names.

But only the name, "Rama" stands out.

If we chant, "Rama" once, it is equal to chanting the 1000 names of Lord Vishnu.

My question is, why is the name "Rama" given more importance or why is it more special and significant than other names of the lord which are supposed to be equal?

We have a Krishna avatar too. But the importance given to Rama name is not given to Krishna Nama.

Can someone provide a reason for this

Answer (score 2):

The name of Rama is given the most importance among names due to a boon asked for by Narada from him. The story features in the Aranya Kanda of the Sri Ramacharitmanas.

Seeing Rama lamenting for Sitaji, Narada is overwhelmed with emotions. He comes to the forest where the two brothers are finding her. It is here that he workshops him and asks for a boon. The relevant verses are as follows:

> जद्यपि प्रभु के नाम अनेका। श्रुति कह अधिक एक तें एका॥४॥
> **राम सकल नामन्ह ते अधिका**। होउ नाथ अघ खग गन बधिका॥५॥
> राका रजनी भगति तव **राम नाम सोइ सोम।**
> अपर नाम उडगन बिमल बसुहुँ भगत उर ब्योम॥४२॥
> Despite the fact that Prabhu has many names, and the Vedas say that each is better than the other, **may Rama be the best among all names**, that acts as a hunter for sins of the form of birds. Your devotion is like a full moon night, **where let Rama nama be like the moon** and all the other names like the nakshastras (stars) and settle in the hearts of your devotees of the form of the sky. 
> *-Doha 42 ka Aranyakanda*

It’s not that the others are any less effective. It’s just that Sri Rama Thirunaamam has been given greater importance for the above reason.